# MercadoPago OrderUpdate IPN

Tags: php, mercadopagosdk

When the URL and ID is generated for payment I get

`URL: foo.com/something_someting_code`

That’s for the mercadopago which is working fine

`ID: 123456_something_something_large_string`

and that's all I get, with that the user can make the payment and that also is working!
Problem is, how do I update that order locally, I store, user info, items info, and ID and URL from the mercadopago sdk...
the IPN is sending a different ID from what I have stored
Generated ID before payment: `321654_sdff_sd_dsf`
ID From the IPN: `987654111`
not even the numbers match.

How can I update my order locally based on the IPN information?